# How to handle unknown number of state variables in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I am getting data from server. I don't know exactly how many items in the api. Therefore, I am using map method in html. Below is the return part.

```
   if (loading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Sidebar />
        </div>
        <h1>LOADING ...</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
  if (error) console.log(error);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Sidebar />
        <h1>Menu Edit Page</h1>
        {edit === false ? (
          <div>
            <table>
              <tbody>
            {
              data?.map((item, index) => (
                <tr>
                  <td>Name: </td>
                  <td>{item?.name}</td>
                  {/* Full_Name: { item.name }, 
                User_Email: { item.email }  */}
                </tr>
              ))
            }
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <Button onClick={() => editMenu()}>edit</Button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <table>
              <tbody>
            {
              data?.map((item, index) => (
                <tr>
                  <td>Name: </td>
                  <input
                  type="text"
                  required="required"
                  placeholder="Edit menu item"
                  name="age"
                  defaultValue={item?.name}
                  onChange={() => itemChange(item?.class, item?.id)}
                  >
                  </input>
                  {/* {item?.name} */}
                  {/* Full_Name: { item.name }, 
                User_Email: { item.email }  */}
                </tr>
              ))
            }
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <Button onClick={() => saveMenu()}>save</Button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

When i use input tag for objects, I need to manipulate them when i click the button. However, I dont know how many objects, so I cannot use state variables. Moreover, i need to know information from object itself when i change the object. Whole code is below.

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Header from "../Components/common/header/header";
import Sidebar from "../Components/common/sidebar/Sidebar";/// IGNORE THIS PAGE
import useFetch from './useFetch';
import { Button } from 'antd';
function MenuEditer() {
  const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState("")
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
  const [buttonPressed, setButtonPressed] = useState(false);
  const { data, loading, error } = useFetch("http://localhost:3001/category/deneme");

  const itemChange = async (clss, id) => {
    alert("beginning of the func");
    // while(!buttonPressed);
    // alert("button pressed");
    // if(clss === "category"){

    // }
    // if(clss === "item"){

    // }
  }
  const saveMenu = async () => {
    setButtonPressed(true);
    setEdit(false);
  }
  const editMenu = async () => {
    setEdit(true);
  }
  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Sidebar />
        </div>
        <h1>LOADING ...</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
  if (error) console.log(error);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Sidebar />
        <h1>Menu Edit Page</h1>
        {edit === false ? (
          <div>
            <table>
              <tbody>
            {
              data?.map((item, index) => (
                <tr>
                  <td>Name: </td>
                  <td>{item?.name}</td>
                  {/* Full_Name: { item.name }, 
                User_Email: { item.email }  */}
                </tr>
              ))
            }
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <Button onClick={() => editMenu()}>edit</Button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <table>
              <tbody>
            {
              data?.map((item, index) => (
                <tr>
                  <td>Name: </td>
                  <input
                  type="text"
                  required="required"
                  placeholder="Edit menu item"
                  name="age"
                  defaultValue={item?.name}
                  onChange={() => itemChange(item?.class, item?.id)}
                  >
                  </input>
                  {/* {item?.name} */}
                  {/* Full_Name: { item.name }, 
                User_Email: { item.email }  */}
                </tr>
              ))
            }
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <Button onClick={() => saveMenu()}>save</Button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MenuEditer;
```

How can I reach object itself from the array, or use useState hook without knowing the length of data? OR, can i write statements of function in onClick attribute? OR, can i use anything else for input form for specifically reach the object and updated string ? The issue may not be clear but I would be very appreciated to any idea. Thanks!

Comment: if I understand will you want to use `useState` to handle changes in the inputs you have, but you don't know their number, right?

Comment: yes. If there is another option to store changes somehow, i can try also.

Comment: You can use an object to store key-value pairs. Eg. `useState({type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"})`

Comment: Thanks so much, but also i need to use these states in the function that triggered by button. Therefore, i guess i should use useState outside of the html return. I hope i understand, can u give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an object to handle the inputs data

at first use `useEffect` to set the initial values of the state

**Note** make sure that the property `name` for the HTML input is the same as the one that comes form the API the

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
  const copy = formData
  data.forEach((item,index)=> {
   copy["item" + index] = {name: item.name, email: item.email}

    setFormData(copy)
})
}, [])
```

then allow the event handler to automatically handle the change

```
const itemChange = (event, index) {
  const copy = formData
  const changedItem = copy["item" + index]
  changedItem[event.target.name] = event.target.value

 setFormData(copy)
  
}
```

in the input element

```
<input
     type="text"
     required={true}
     placeholder="Edit menu item"
     name="age"  // make sure the name is same as the property name that comes form the api
     value={formData["item" + index].age}
     onChange={(e) => itemChange(e, index)}
 />
```